# cloudinary multiple file upload error nodejs

Tags: node.js, backend, mern, template-engine, cloudinary

I am trying to do a multiple file upload using Cloudinary, but for some reason, it only picks the last file I upload and not all 4 of the files, it returns only one file in the array.

Here are the files

**Multer.js**

```
const path = require("path");

//setting the storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname)
    );
  },
});

// Check File Type
function checkFileType(file, cb) {
  // Allowed extension format
  const filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png|pdf/;
  // Check the extension format
  const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
  // Check mime
  const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype);

  if (mimetype && extname) {
    return cb(null, true);
  } else {
    req.flash("error", "Invalid File");
    cb("ERROR: Please upload a valid filetype");
    return res.redirect("back");
  }
}

//initialize the file uplaod
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,

  //limits file size
  fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
    checkFileType(file, cb);
  },
});

module.exports = { upload };
```

***cloudinary.js***

```
const { CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME, CLOUDINARY_API_KEY, CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET } =
  process.env;

const cloudinarySetup = async () => {
  cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
    api_secret: CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
  });
};

// cloudinary upload method
const cloudinaryMediaUpload = async (file, folder) => {
  await cloudinarySetup();
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    cloudinary.uploader.upload(
      file,
      {
        resource_type: "auto",
        folder: folder,
      },
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        resolve({
          url: result.secure_url,
          id: result.public_id,
        });
      }
    );
  });
};

module.exports = { cloudinaryMediaUpload };
```

***defaultController.js***

```
const { Business } = require("../models/business");
const { cloudinaryMediaUpload } = require(".././config/cloudinary");

module.exports = {
  indexGet: (req, res) => {
    let pageTitle = "Home";
    res.render("default/index", { pageTitle });
  },

  aboutGet: (req, res) => {
    let pageTitle = "About";
    res.render("default/about", { pageTitle });
  },

  contactGet: (req, res) => {
    let pageTitle = "Contact";
    res.render("default/contact", { pageTitle });
  },

  registerGet: (req, res) => {
    let pageTitle = "Register";
    const { businessName, businessAddress, businessPhone } = req.body;
    res.render("default/register", {
      pageTitle,
      businessName,
      businessAddress,
      businessPhone,
    });
  },

  registerPost: async (req, res) => {
    const { businessName, businessAddress, businessPhone, businessCategory } =
      req.body;

    // console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);
    let errors = [];

    // Checking Required Field
    if (
      !businessName ||
      !businessAddress ||
      !businessPhone ||
      !businessCategory
    ) {
      errors.push({ msg: "All fields are required" });
    }
    let validatePhone = validatePhoneNumberSync(businessPhone);
    if (!validatePhone.isValid === true) {
      errors.push({ msg: "Invalid phone number" });
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
      let pageTitle = "Register";
      res.render("default/register", {
        pageTitle,
        businessName,
        businessAddress,
        businessPhone,
        errors,
      });
    } else {
      Business.findOne({ businessName }).then(async (buss) => {
        if (buss) {
          errors.push({
            msg: "A business with this name is already registered",
          });
          let pageTitle = "Register";
          res.render("default/register", {
            pageTitle,
            businessName,
            businessAddress,
            businessPhone,
            errors,
          });
        } else {
          // uploading files to cloud
          const uploader = async (path) => {
            const folderName = businessName
              .trim()
              .toLowerCase()
              .replace(/^[^A-Z0-9]+/gi, function (match) {
                return arguments[2].toUpperCase();
              });

            console.log(folderName);

            await cloudinaryMediaUpload(path, "folderName");
          };
          const urls = [];
          const files = req.files;
          for (const file of files) {
            const { path } = file;
            const cloudPath = await uploader(path);
            urls.push(cloudPath);
          }

          const newBusiness = new Business({
            businessName,
            businessAddress,
            businessPhone,
            businessCategory,
          });
          newBusiness.save();
          req.flash("success_msg", "Business successfully registered");
          res.redirect("/");
        }
      });
    }
  },
};
```

***register.ejs***

```
<%- include("../partials/default/header") %>



  <div class="form_wrapper">
    <div class="form_container">
      <div class="title_container">
        <h2 style="color: #65b54a;">Business Registration</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="row clearfix">
        <div class="">
          <%- include ("../partials/messages"); %>
            <form action="/register" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
              <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col_half">
                  <div class="input_field"> <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" name="businessName" placeholder="Business Name" required
                      value="<%= businessName || '' %>" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col_half">
                  <div class="input_field"> <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" name="businessAddress" placeholder="Business Address" required
                      value="<%= businessAddress || '' %>" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col_half">
                  <div class="input_field"> <span><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" name="businessPhone" placeholder="Business Phone Number" required
                      value="<%= businessPhone || '' %>" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col_half">
                  <div class="input_field select_option">
                    <select name="businessCategory">
                      <option selected disabled>Business Category</option>
                      <option>Technology</option>
                      <option>Agriculture</option>
                      <option>Fashion</option>
                      <option>Entertainment</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="select_arrow"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-------------------------Files upload section---------------->
              <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col_half">
                  <div class="input_field d-flex justify-content-around">
                    <input type="file" name="bussFile" multiple accept=".pdf, .png, .jpg, .jpeg" id="img"
                      style="display:none;" />
                    <label for="img" class="btn btn-success"><span class="d-none d-md-inline mr-2"><i aria-hidden="true"
                          class="fas fa-upload"></i></span>Upload Incorporation Document</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col_half">
                  <div class="input_field d-flex justify-content-around">
                    <input type="file" name="bussFile" multiple accept=".pdf, .png, .jpg, .jpeg" id="img"
                      style="display:none;" />
                    <label for="img" class="btn btn-success"><span class="d-none d-md-inline mr-2"><i aria-hidden="true"
                          class="fas fa-upload"></i></span>Upload Company's Profile</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col_half">
                  <div class="input_field d-flex justify-content-around">
                    <input type="file" name="bussFile" multiple accept=".pdf, .png, .jpg, .jpeg" id="img"
                      style="display:none;" />
                    <label for="img" class="btn btn-success"><span class="d-none d-md-inline mr-2"><i aria-hidden="true"
                          class="fas fa-upload"></i></span>Upload Financial Statements</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col_half">
                  <div class="input_field d-flex justify-content-around">
                    <input type="file" name="bussFile" multiple accept=".pdf, .png, .jpg, .jpeg" id="img"
                      style="display:none;" />
                    <label for="img" class="btn btn-success"><span class="d-none d-md-inline mr-2"><i aria-hidden="true"
                          class="fas fa-upload"></i></span>Upload Investment Pitch Deck</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <input class="button" type="submit" value="Register" />
              <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
                Register
              </button> -->
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <%- include("../partials/default/footer") %>
```

And this happens to be the array I get back when I submit. Only the last file upload was picked and not all 4 of the uploads

```
[
  {
    fieldname: 'bussFile',
    originalname: 'tab.png',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    destination: 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp',
    filename: 'bussFile-1664784129792.png',
    path: 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\bussFile-1664784129792.png',
    size: 68329
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I check out the documentation here -
It looks like only a single "file" is supported at one time.

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_required_parameters

Details about how to upload more in parallel here:
[https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520662-How-can-I-bulk-upload-my-images-#:~:text=Cloudinary's%20upload%20API%20supports%20a,files%20in%20a%20short%20term](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520662-How-can-I-bulk-upload-my-images-#:%7E:text=Cloudinary%27s%20upload%20API%20supports%20a,files%20in%20a%20short%20term).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).